# Concatenate two PySpark dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to concatenate two PySpark dataframes with some columns that are only on one of them:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import randn, rand

df_1 = sqlContext.range(0, 10)

+--+
|id|
+--+
| 0|
| 1|
| 2|
| 3|
| 4|
| 5|
| 6|
| 7|
| 8|
| 9|
+--+

df_2 = sqlContext.range(11, 20)

+--+
|id|
+--+
| 10|
| 11|
| 12|
| 13|
| 14|
| 15|
| 16|
| 17|
| 18|
| 19|
+--+

df_1 = df_1.select("id", rand(seed=10).alias("uniform"), randn(seed=27).alias("normal"))
df_2 = df_2.select("id", rand(seed=10).alias("uniform"), randn(seed=27).alias("normal_2"))
```

and now I want to generate a third dataframe. I would like something like pandas `concat`:

```
df_1.show()
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|             uniform|              normal|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  0|  0.8122802274304282|  1.2423430583597714|
|  1|  0.8642043127063618|  0.3900018344856156|
|  2|  0.8292577771850476|  1.8077401259195247|
|  3|   0.198558705368724| -0.4270585782850261|
|  4|0.012661361966674889|   0.702634599720141|
|  5|  0.8535692890157796|-0.42355804115129153|
|  6|  0.3723296190171911|  1.3789648582622995|
|  7|  0.9529794127670571| 0.16238718777444605|
|  8|  0.9746632635918108| 0.02448061333761742|
|  9|   0.513622008243935|  0.7626741803250845|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+

df_2.show()
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|             uniform|            normal_2|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| 11|  0.3221262660507942|  1.0269298899109824|
| 12|  0.4030672316912547|   1.285648175568798|
| 13|  0.9690555459609131|-0.22986601831364423|
| 14|0.011913836266515876|  -0.678915153834693|
| 15|  0.9359607054250594|-0.16557488664743034|
| 16| 0.45680471157575453| -0.3885563551710555|
| 17|  0.6411908952297819|  0.9161177183227823|
| 18|  0.5669232696934479|  0.7270125277020573|
| 19|   0.513622008243935|  0.7626741803250845|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+

#do some concatenation here, how?

df_concat.show()

| id|             uniform|              normal| normal_2   |
+---+--------------------+--------------------+------------+
|  0|  0.8122802274304282|  1.2423430583597714| None       |
|  1|  0.8642043127063618|  0.3900018344856156| None       |
|  2|  0.8292577771850476|  1.8077401259195247| None       |
|  3|   0.198558705368724| -0.4270585782850261| None       |
|  4|0.012661361966674889|   0.702634599720141| None       |
|  5|  0.8535692890157796|-0.42355804115129153| None       |
|  6|  0.3723296190171911|  1.3789648582622995| None       |
|  7|  0.9529794127670571| 0.16238718777444605| None       |
|  8|  0.9746632635918108| 0.02448061333761742| None       |
|  9|   0.513622008243935|  0.7626741803250845| None       |
| 11|  0.3221262660507942|  None              | 0.123      |
| 12|  0.4030672316912547|  None              |0.12323     |
| 13|  0.9690555459609131|  None              |0.123       |
| 14|0.011913836266515876|  None              |0.18923     |
| 15|  0.9359607054250594|  None              |0.99123     |
| 16| 0.45680471157575453|  None              |0.123       |
| 17|  0.6411908952297819|  None              |1.123       |
| 18|  0.5669232696934479|  None              |0.10023     |
| 19|   0.513622008243935|  None              |0.916332123 |
+---+--------------------+--------------------+------------+
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Maybe you can try creating the unexisting columns and calling [`union`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=join#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union) (`unionAll` for Spark 1.6 or lower):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

cols = ['id', 'uniform', 'normal', 'normal_2']    

df_1_new = df_1.withColumn("normal_2", lit(None)).select(cols)
df_2_new = df_2.withColumn("normal", lit(None)).select(cols)

result = df_1_new.union(df_2_new)

# To remove the duplicates:

result = result.dropDuplicates()
```

Comment: `unionAll()` is deprecated in spark 2.0. use `union()` instead

Comment: you can rename using `withColumnRenamed` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=selectexpr#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed

Comment: Any way to remove duplicate rows while doing the union @Daniel

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: @javan.rajpopat you can do `result.dropDuplicates()` to remove duplicates.

Comment: @Daniel de Paula : Could you please answer this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276056/pyspark-notebooks-overloads-cluster-in-databricks

Comment: `union()` works positionally. It would be much safer to use `unionByName()` to ensure that columns are matched by name in the union.

Answer (score 95):

```
df_concat = df_1.union(df_2)
```

The dataframes may need to have identical columns, in which case you can use `withColumn()` to create `normal_1` and `normal_2`

Comment: Thanks. The issue, as I said above, is that the columns are not identical between the two dataframes.

Comment: add the extra columns to the dataframe.
df.withColumn('NewColumnName',lit('RequiredValue')

Comment: Any way to remove duplicate rows while doing the union @David

Comment: use the drop duplicates function

Comment: Also the order of columns in both the dataframes should be same. Otherwise it gives weird results.        
From the docs `Also as standard in SQL, this function resolves columns by position (not by name).`

Comment: What if you want to do multiple at once? You could concatenate your command another time but it doesn't look too clean...

Answer (score 39):

**unionByName** is a built-in option available in spark which is available from spark 2.3.0.

with **spark version 3.1.0**, there is **allowMissingColumns** option with the default value set to False to handle missing columns. Even if both dataframes don't have the same set of columns, this function will work, setting missing column values to null in the resulting dataframe.

```
df_1.unionByName(df_2, allowMissingColumns=True).show()

+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|             uniform|              normal|            normal_2|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  0|  0.8122802274304282|  1.2423430583597714|                null|
|  1|  0.8642043127063618|  0.3900018344856156|                null|
|  2|  0.8292577771850476|  1.8077401259195247|                null|
|  3|   0.198558705368724| -0.4270585782850261|                null|
|  4|0.012661361966674889|   0.702634599720141|                null|
|  5|  0.8535692890157796|-0.42355804115129153|                null|
|  6|  0.3723296190171911|  1.3789648582622995|                null|
|  7|  0.9529794127670571| 0.16238718777444605|                null|
|  8|  0.9746632635918108| 0.02448061333761742|                null|
|  9|   0.513622008243935|  0.7626741803250845|                null|
| 11|  0.3221262660507942|                null|  1.0269298899109824|
| 12|  0.4030672316912547|                null|   1.285648175568798|
| 13|  0.9690555459609131|                null|-0.22986601831364423|
| 14|0.011913836266515876|                null|  -0.678915153834693|
| 15|  0.9359607054250594|                null|-0.16557488664743034|
| 16| 0.45680471157575453|                null| -0.3885563551710555|
| 17|  0.6411908952297819|                null|  0.9161177183227823|
| 18|  0.5669232696934479|                null|  0.7270125277020573|
| 19|   0.513622008243935|                null|  0.7626741803250845|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use unionByName to make this:

```
df = df_1.unionByName(df_2)
```

unionByName is available since Spark 2.3.0.

Comment: Ran into an exception: `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Cannot resolve column name "normal" among (id, uniform, normal_2);'`

Comment: It’s because both dataframe need the same column names.

Comment: Now I can avoid using `select` to reorder the columns before appending the dataframes. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

To concatenate multiple pyspark dataframes into one:

```
from functools import reduce

df = reduce(lambda x,y:x.union(y), [df_1,df_2])
```

And you can replace the list of [df_1, df_2] to a list of any length.

Answer (score 11):

To make it more generic of keeping both columns in `df1` and `df2`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# Keep all columns in either df1 or df2
def outter_union(df1, df2):

    # Add missing columns to df1
    left_df = df1
    for column in set(df2.columns) - set(df1.columns):
        left_df = left_df.withColumn(column, F.lit(None))

    # Add missing columns to df2
    right_df = df2
    for column in set(df1.columns) - set(df2.columns):
        right_df = right_df.withColumn(column, F.lit(None))

    # Make sure columns are ordered the same
    return left_df.union(right_df.select(left_df.columns))
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do it, in case it is still useful: I ran this in pyspark shell, Python version 2.7.12 and my Spark install was version 2.0.1.

PS: I guess you meant to use different seeds for the df_1 df_2 and the code below reflects that.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import randn, rand
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_1 = sqlContext.range(0, 10)
df_2 = sqlContext.range(11, 20)
df_1 = df_1.select("id", rand(seed=10).alias("uniform"), randn(seed=27).alias("normal"))
df_2 = df_2.select("id", rand(seed=11).alias("uniform"), randn(seed=28).alias("normal_2"))

def get_uniform(df1_uniform, df2_uniform):
    if df1_uniform:
        return df1_uniform
    if df2_uniform:
        return df2_uniform

u_get_uniform = F.udf(get_uniform, FloatType())

df_3 = df_1.join(df_2, on = "id", how = 'outer').select("id", u_get_uniform(df_1["uniform"], df_2["uniform"]).alias("uniform"), "normal", "normal_2").orderBy(F.col("id"))
```

Here are the outputs I get:

```
df_1.show()
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
| id|            uniform|              normal|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
|  0|0.41371264720975787|  0.5888539012978773|
|  1| 0.7311719281896606|  0.8645537008427937|
|  2| 0.1982919638208397| 0.06157382353970104|
|  3|0.12714181165849525|  0.3623040918178586|
|  4| 0.7604318153406678|-0.49575204523675975|
|  5|0.12030715258495939|  1.0854146699817222|
|  6|0.12131363910425985| -0.5284523629183004|
|  7|0.44292918521277047| -0.4798519469521663|
|  8| 0.8898784253886249| -0.8820294772950535|
|  9|0.03650707717266999| -2.1591956435415334|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+

df_2.show()
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
| id|            uniform|            normal_2|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+
| 11| 0.1982919638208397| 0.06157382353970104|
| 12|0.12714181165849525|  0.3623040918178586|
| 13|0.12030715258495939|  1.0854146699817222|
| 14|0.12131363910425985| -0.5284523629183004|
| 15|0.44292918521277047| -0.4798519469521663|
| 16| 0.8898784253886249| -0.8820294772950535|
| 17| 0.2731073068483362|-0.15116027592854422|
| 18| 0.7784518091224375| -0.3785563841011868|
| 19|0.43776394586845413| 0.47700719174464357|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+

df_3.show()
+---+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+                     
| id|    uniform|              normal|            normal_2|
+---+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  0| 0.41371265|  0.5888539012978773|                null|
|  1|  0.7311719|  0.8645537008427937|                null|
|  2| 0.19829196| 0.06157382353970104|                null|
|  3| 0.12714182|  0.3623040918178586|                null|
|  4|  0.7604318|-0.49575204523675975|                null|
|  5|0.120307155|  1.0854146699817222|                null|
|  6| 0.12131364| -0.5284523629183004|                null|
|  7| 0.44292918| -0.4798519469521663|                null|
|  8| 0.88987845| -0.8820294772950535|                null|
|  9|0.036507078| -2.1591956435415334|                null|
| 11| 0.19829196|                null| 0.06157382353970104|
| 12| 0.12714182|                null|  0.3623040918178586|
| 13|0.120307155|                null|  1.0854146699817222|
| 14| 0.12131364|                null| -0.5284523629183004|
| 15| 0.44292918|                null| -0.4798519469521663|
| 16| 0.88987845|                null| -0.8820294772950535|
| 17| 0.27310732|                null|-0.15116027592854422|
| 18|  0.7784518|                null| -0.3785563841011868|
| 19| 0.43776396|                null| 0.47700719174464357|
+---+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: a tempting approach that doesnt work is to add an index col to each df with `pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id())  `    and then to do a join on that column.  The monotonically_increasing_id isnt guaranteed to start at 0 and also isnt guaranteed to use successive integers.

Answer (score 2):

Above answers are very elegant. I have written this function long back where i was also struggling to concatenate two dataframe with distinct columns.

Suppose you have dataframe sdf1 and sdf2

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def unequal_union_sdf(sdf1, sdf2):
    s_df1_schema = set((x.name, x.dataType) for x in sdf1.schema)
    s_df2_schema = set((x.name, x.dataType) for x in sdf2.schema)

    for i,j in s_df2_schema.difference(s_df1_schema):
        sdf1 = sdf1.withColumn(i,F.lit(None).cast(j))

    for i,j in s_df1_schema.difference(s_df2_schema):
        sdf2 = sdf2.withColumn(i,F.lit(None).cast(j))

    common_schema_colnames = sdf1.columns
    sdk = \
        sdf1.select(common_schema_colnames).union(sdf2.select(common_schema_colnames))
    return sdk 

sdf_concat = unequal_union_sdf(sdf1, sdf2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
ps.concat([df_1.pandas_api('id'),df_2.pandas_api('id')])
```

out:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|            uniform|              normal|            normal_2|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|0.03422639313807285| 0.45800664187768786|                null|
| 0.3654625958161396| 0.16420866768809156|                null|
| 0.4175019040792016| -1.0451987154313813|                null|
|0.16452185994603707|  0.8306551181802446|                null|
|0.18141810315190554|  1.3792681955381285|                null|
| 0.9697474945375325|  0.5991404703866096|                null|
|0.34084319330900115| -1.4298752463301871|                null|
| 0.4725977369833597|-0.19668314148825305|                null|
| 0.5996723933366402| -0.6950946460326453|                null|
| 0.6396141227834357|-0.07706276399864868|                null|
|0.03422639313807285|                null| 0.45800664187768786|
| 0.3654625958161396|                null| 0.16420866768809156|
| 0.4175019040792016|                null| -1.0451987154313813|
|0.18141810315190554|                null|  1.3792681955381285|
|0.49595620559530806|                null|-0.02511484514022299|
| 0.9697474945375325|                null|  0.5991404703866096|
| 0.4725977369833597|                null|-0.19668314148825305|
| 0.5996723933366402|                null| -0.6950946460326453|
| 0.6396141227834357|                null|-0.07706276399864868|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to concat i.e union all records between 2 dataframes. Utilize simple unionByName method in pyspark, which concats 2 dataframes along axis 0 as done by pandas concat method.

Now suppose you have df1 with columns id, uniform, normal and also you have df2 which has columns id, uniform and normal_2. In order to get a third df3 with columns id, uniform, normal, normal_2. You must add the non-existent columns in either of the 2 dfs: df1 and df2.

```
# Add df1 columns which are not in df2 in df2 as null columns
for column in df1.columns:
    if column not in df2.columns:
         df2 = df2.withColumn(column, lit(None))

# Add df2 columns which are not in df1 in df1 as null columns
for column in df2.columns:
    if column not in df1.columns:
         df1 = df1.withColumn(column, lit(None))

df3 = df1.unionByName(df2)
```

[Pyspark unionByName documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you ...

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import randn, rand, lit, coalesce, col
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_1 = sqlContext.range(0, 6)
df_2 = sqlContext.range(3, 10)
df_1 = df_1.select("id", lit("old").alias("source"))
df_2 = df_2.select("id")

df_1.show()
df_2.show()
df_3 = df_1.alias("df_1").join(df_2.alias("df_2"), df_1.id == df_2.id, "outer")\
  .select(\
    [coalesce(df_1.id, df_2.id).alias("id")] +\
    [col("df_1." + c) for c in df_1.columns if c != "id"])\
  .sort("id")
df_3.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this in this way:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
df_1.createOrReplaceTempView("tab_1")
df_2.createOrReplaceTempView("tab_2")
df_concat=spark.sql("select tab_1.id,tab_1.uniform,tab_1.normal,tab_2.normal_2  from tab_1 tab_1 left join tab_2 tab_2 on tab_1.uniform=tab_2.uniform\
                union\
                select tab_2.id,tab_2.uniform,tab_1.normal,tab_2.normal_2  from tab_2 tab_2 left join tab_1 tab_1 on tab_1.uniform=tab_2.uniform")
df_concat.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to implement pandas append functionality in pyspark and what I created a custom function where we can concat 2 or more data frame even they are having different no. of columns only condition is if dataframes have  identical name then their datatype should be same/match.

I have written a custom function to merge 2 dataframes.

```
def append_dfs(df1,df2):
    list1 = df1.columns
    list2 = df2.columns
    for col in list2:
        if(col not in list1):
            df1 = df1.withColumn(col, F.lit(None))
    for col in list1:
        if(col not in list2):
            df2 = df2.withColumn(col, F.lit(None))
    return df1.unionByName(df2)
```

## usage:

1. concate 2 dataframes

   final_df = append_dfs(df1,df2)
2. 1. concate more than 2(say3) dataframes

   final_df = append_dfs(append_dfs(df1,df2),df3)

## example:

## df1:

[image]

## df2:

[image]

result=append_dfs(df1,df2)

## result :

[image: +------+---+-------+---------+ | Name|Age|Married| Address| +------+---+-------+---------+ | Jai| 27| true| null| |Princi| 24| false| null| |Gaurav| 22| false| null| | Anuj| 22| true| null| | Jai| 27| null| Delhi| |Princi| 24| null| Kanpur| |Gaurav| 22| null|Allahabad| | Anuj| 22| null| null| +------+---+-------+---------+]

Hope this will useful.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe, you want to concatenate more of two Dataframes. 
I found a issue which use pandas Dataframe conversion.

Suppose you have 3 spark Dataframe who want to concatenate.

The code is the following:

```
list_dfs = []
list_dfs_ = []

df = spark.read.json('path_to_your_jsonfile.json',multiLine = True)
df2 = spark.read.json('path_to_your_jsonfile2.json',multiLine = True)
df3 = spark.read.json('path_to_your_jsonfile3.json',multiLine = True)

list_dfs.extend([df,df2,df3])

for df in list_dfs : 

    df = df.select([column for column in df.columns]).toPandas()
    list_dfs_.append(df)

list_dfs.clear()

df_ = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd.concat(list_dfs_))
```