# Appending columns to pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I'd like to append columns from one pyspark dataframe to another.

In pandas, the command would look like

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':['a','b','c']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'y':[1,2,3]})

pd.concat((df1, df2), axis = 1)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in pyspark?  All I can find is either concatenating the contents of a column or doing a join.

Comment: You have to do a join, but first you need to have a join key (like the index in a pandas dataframe).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate two dataframes pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305012/concatenate-two-dataframes-pyspark) and [How to concatenate/append multiple Spark dataframes column wise in Pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44320699/5858851)