# Making Many Empty Columns in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a list of many dataframes each with a subset schema of a master schema. In order to union these dataframes, I need to construct a common schema among all the dataframes. My thought is that I need to create empty columns for all the missing columns for each of the dataframes. I have about on average 80 missing features and 100s of dataframes.

This is somewhat of a duplicate or inspired by [Concatenate two PySpark dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332434/concatenate-two-pyspark-dataframes)

I am currently implementing things this way:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

for df in dfs:    # list of dataframes
    for feature in missing_features:   # list of strings
        df = df.withColumn(feature, lit(None).cast("string"))
```

This seems to be taking a significant amount of time. Is there a faster way to concat these dataframes with null in place of missing features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to cut time a little by replacing your code with:

```
cols = ["*"] + [lit(None).cast("string").alias(f) for f in missing_features]

dfs_new = [df.select(cols) for df in dfs]
```

Comment: For a subset of data, this method took 455ms and the method I have posted above took 13s. Thanks a bunch!