# How can I union multiple datasets into one whole big dataset with python spark?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, bigdata

I want to make one big dataset from 17 different csv files. Each contains like 200k rows and same columns.
So what I want to do is just create one single dataframe so I can work with it later.

I tried to look for SQL joins but it seems they require one ID to join.
the datasets doesn't single IDs.

Comment: you don't want to join on a column?   so do you want to append data from all csv files?

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332434/concatenate-two-pyspark-dataframes)

Comment: I saw that questions earlier but didn't pay attention to one of the answers... it seems the `df_concat = df.union(df2)` will do. Just it takes only one dataset at a time. tks @pyofey

Comment: `from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)` This did the trick... now I have one big dataset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import multiple csv files in a single load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639956/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-in-a-single-load). Instead of using join or union, simply read all the csv files at ones to create a single dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a big data frame out of the 17 csv files which have same columns,

1. Use `glob()` to list your files
2. Use a generator expression to read files
3. Use `concat()` method to combine them
4. Write the new dataframe into a new csv file.

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

all_csv_files = glob('csv_folder/*.csv')
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(csv_file) for csv_file in all_csv_files), ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv('final_csv.csv', index=False)
```