# How to combine two dataset into one in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Let's say we have two dataset:

Dataset 1:

```
id  name    
1   James
2   Tom
```

Dataset 2:

```
id   name
1    Bond
2    Jerry
```

I want dataset 3 in the following format

Dataset 3:

```
id   name
1    James
2    Tom
3    Bond
4    Jerry
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate two PySpark dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332434/concatenate-two-pyspark-dataframes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly straightforward,

`df3 = df1.union(df2)`