# Pyspark notebooks overloads cluster in databricks

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have a pyspark code where I use multiple UDFs. The aim of the code is to generate human readable commentary based on multiple levels of organisational data. The data is 4M rows and 32 columns all of which are required sequentially.

Input dataframe columns:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5.....col30  amt1    amt2    amt3    amt4
```

The code will take 2 columns at a time, generate statement based on the 4 amount columns and then take next set of columns and continue till col30. Some of those levels have different logic than others.

```
Level1 : col1 and col2 along with 4 amt columns -->save output in output1 dataframe
Level2 : col2 and col3 along with 4 amt columns -->save output in output2 dataframe
Level3 : col3 and col4 along with 4 amt columns -->save output in output3 dataframe
Level4 : col4 and col5 along with 4 amt columns -->save output in output4 dataframe
and so on...
```

I need to do this same thing over around 42 times based on the different data parameters.

Now at the end of each iteration, i perform a reduce function to combine all the output dataframes and then write to parquet file. This happens at each iteration. Once all the iterations are completed, i read the parquet file. Indentations are for `for` loop

```py
df_list = [output1, output2, output3, ....]
df_1 = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, df_list).cache()  
df_1.coalesce(1).write.mode('append').parquet(/FileStore/tables/newfile)
df_final_temp = spark.read.parquet(/FileStore/tables/newfile)
```

Issue I have is that whenever i write the parquet file it takes around 20 minutes. Each time it would have approx 56 rows and 12 columns. When i read the parquet file it takes around 2hrs. It should have around 2300 rows and 12 columns. This mostly results in spark server getting restarted automatically. *Code itself runs for 3hrs before initiating the write towards parquet file.*

Is there any way to optimize this?

My databricks cluster has 8 cores and 56GB memory with 16 cores. any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: why do you use `coalesce`? remove it