# How To merge two columns into rows in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have dataframe in pyspark like this:

| Id | Time Interval 1 | Time Interval 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4w | 24d |
| 1 | 8w | 12d |

I like to merge time interval 1 and 2 so the final dataframe like this:

| Id | Time Interval |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4w |
| 1 | 8w |
| 1 | 12d |
| 1 | 24d |

Comment: Try using the `union` operation in PySpark. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332434/concatenate-two-pyspark-dataframes

Answer (score 1):

for pyspark >= 3.4, you can use `melt`

```
cols = df.select(df.colRegex('`Time Interval.*`')).columns
result = df.melt(['Id'], cols, variableColumnName='col', valueColumnName='Time interval').drop('col')
```

for pyspark < 3.4, create an array from interval columns then explode

```
cols = df.select(df.colRegex('`Time Interval.*`')).columns
result = df.select('id', F.explode(F.array(*[f'`{c}`' for c in cols])).alias('Time Interval'))
```

Result

```
+---+-------------+
| id|Time Interval|
+---+-------------+
|  1|           4w|
|  1|          24d|
|  1|           8w|
|  1|          12d|
+---+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should be using the melt function.**

Here is what I have done: I made a copy your example into `.csv` file with the name `df1.file`

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

# Initialize a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("codeapplied").getOrCreate()

# Load your DataFrame from the CSV file
#`.option()` lets you replace the columns headings with the default pyspark c0 & c1
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("df1.csv")

# Specify the columns to melt
melted_df = df.select("Id", expr("stack(2, `Time Interval 1`, `Time Interval 2`) as (Time_Interval)"))

# Show the melted DataFrame
melted_df.show()

# Stop the Spark session
spark.stop()
```

Here is quick snapshot of how the output looks. Hope it helped you out.

[image]

**To understand more about how melt works:**

- [How to melt Spark DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670103/how-to-melt-spark-dataframe)
- [pyspark.sql.DataFrame.melt](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.melt.html)

**Few other similar interesting topics:**

- [Concatenate columns in Apache Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450846/concatenate-columns-in-apache-spark-dataframe)
- [Concatenate two PySpark dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332434/concatenate-two-pyspark-dataframes)